# PHP: Efficiently Search through Collections

Tags: php, data-structures

I have collections of numbers (arbitrary order) to store.

psuedocode:

```
id_a:[3,5,7,11]
id_x:[3,5,10,21]
id_b:[12,24,25,26]
etc.
```

**I need to be able to search through all the collections and return the group_IDs.
For example, if I look up 5, I should get back `['id_a','id_x']`.** I want to do this efficiently with some sort of mapping, **not** by looping through all numbers of all collections. **I also want to be able to map directly to each key and get back the collection (e.g., `'id_x'` returns `[3,5,10,21]`)** ; again I prefer this be done efficiently **without** looping through the keys.

**edit:**
I could use the numbers as the keys and efficiently get back 'id_*'. Or, I could go the other way and use 'id_*' as keys and efficiently get back the array of numbers. However, I want to be able to go efficiently in both directions. I guess I could maintain two arrays, but that seems messy.

Comment: You have to loop _somehow_ through the values to find if it exists in the array (even if that loop is hidden in a built-in php function)

Comment: @kniitt I could use the numbers as the keys and efficiently get back 'id_*'. I could go the other way and use 'id_*' as keys and efficiently get back the array of numbers. However,i want to be ableto go efficiently in both directions. I guess I could have two structures, but that seems messy.

Comment: @JohnR: yeah, using two structures trades higher memory usage with faster runtime. A DB table with two columns and two keys could be quite fast here (if you are already using a DB)

Comment: It's a good thought @knittl . This is parsing a fairly large ajax query (hence the need for efficiency). I hoped not to open a database query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples all show the array values in sorted order. If they are always in sorted order, then you can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find known values. This code:

```
function binarySearch($needle, array $haystack) {
    $high = count($haystack) - 1;
    $low = 0;
    $mid = false;
    while ($high >= $low) {
        $mid = ($high + $low) >> 1;
        $t = $needle - $haystack[$mid];
        if ($t < 0) {
            $high = $mid - 1;
        } elseif ($t > 0) {
            $low = $mid + 1;
        } else {
            return $mid;
        }
    }

    return $mid;
}

function searchArrays($needle) {
    static $id_a = array(3,5,7,11);
    static $id_x = array(3,5,10,21);
    static $id_b = array(12,24,25,26);
    static $arrayNames = array('id_a', 'id_x', 'id_b');

    $rv = array();
    foreach ($arrayNames as $arrayName) {
        $array = $$arrayName;
        $index = binarySearch($needle, $array);
        if ($array[$index] == $needle) {
            $rv[] = $arrayName;
        }
    }

    return $rv;
}

$needles = range(3,8);
foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    $result = searchArrays($needle);
    printf("searchArrays(%s)=%s\n", $needle, join(', ', $result));
}
```

will output the following:

```
searchArrays(3)=id_a, id_x
searchArrays(4)=
searchArrays(5)=id_a, id_x
searchArrays(6)=
searchArrays(7)=id_a
searchArrays(8)=
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. Yes, I could make a point to maintain the order of the arrays and use a variation of this. Please, if you have a second, remind me what ">>" does (I could not Google it).

Comment: `>>` is a right shift, which is equivalent with multiplying by factors of two.

Comment: Actually `>>` is *dividing* by 2, but it will always give an integer result.